# Does Unlocked Package support Person Account?

Tags: salesforcedx, package

I'm having problem trying to create Unlocked Package with dependencies on Person Account. So, I would like to know if it is officially supported or not?

Answer (score 5):

You should create your package version using your scratch org definition file.

Here is the command:

```
sfdx force:package:version:create -p <<PackageName>> -d <<PackagePath>> --wait 10 -x --definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json
```